# creating new user in postgres and granting permissions

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am launching postgres in docker container by injecting .sql script into Docker entrypoint.

I want to create a new login role and grant full access to it on my schema. Currently, schema ownerships is getting assigned to deafult user postgres. Table is getting created though.

How can I achieve this?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres 

ENV POSTGRES_DB MYAPP
COPY /script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**script.sql :**

```
CREATE SCHEMA "MYAPP";
          
CREATE USER MYAPP WITH LOGIN  SUPERUSER  INHERIT  CREATEDB   CREATEROLE   NOREPLICATION";


GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "MYAPP" TO MYAPP;


CREATE TABLE "MYAPP"."SYSTEM_CONFIG_MASTER"
(
    "CONFIG_ITEM_ID" character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "CONFIG_GROUP_NAME" character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "CONFIG_NAME" character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "CONFIG_VALUE" character varying(2000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "SYSTEM_CONFIG_MASTER_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("CONFIG_ITEM_ID")
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I want to assign full ownership of this MYAPP schema ( or database)  to user MYAPP.

Please help.

**Edit:**

Alter Schema did help in changing owner. But privileges aren't getting reflected even after using

```
CREATE SCHEMA myapp;
          
CREATE USER myapp;


 ALTER SCHEMA myapp owner to myapp;  ( this is working)
    
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myapp TO myapp; ( this is not)




                           List of schemas
    Name    |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description
------------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 myapp      | myapp    |                      |
 TESTDB     | postgres  |                      |
 public     | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
            |          | =UC/postgres         |
(3 rows)

myapp=#
```

why privileges aren't reflecting?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1):

As @a_horse_with_no_name suggested avoid using "" while mentioning schema name, table name or column name. Also there's lots of noise created so I have just removed.

```
CREATE TABLE MYAPP.SYSTEM_CONFIG_MASTER
(
    CONFIG_ITEM_ID character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    CONFIG_GROUP_NAME character varying(100),
    CONFIG_NAME character varying(100),
    CONFIG_VALUE character varying(2000),
    CONSTRAINT SYSTEM_CONFIG_MASTER_pkey PRIMARY KEY (CONFIG_ITEM_ID)
);
```

From the below statement that you have ran:-

```
CREATE USER MYAPP WITH LOGIN  SUPERUSER  INHERIT  CREATEDB   CREATEROLE   NOREPLICATION;
```

It already appears to be a super user. However if myapp user is not an owner then

You can run below statement from owner of that schema /super user

Syntax:    `Alter schema schema_name owner to user_name;`

Code: `alter schema myapp owner to myapp;`

Comment: Hey @Nik, your hint to ALter it helped. But privileges aren't reflected. Edited the logs above. Can u pls check?

Comment: Through which user are you running this statement
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myapp TO myapp; ( this is not) and what error is it giving?